# Css3 keyframes not working even with vendor prefixes

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a side navigation bar and for mobile phones I need to move it on x axis using a toggle button, here is my code

this is the scss code:

```
mat-sidenav{
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  width:230px;
  height:100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.hide{
  -webkit-animation: mymove 0.15s;
  animation: mymove 0.15s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0%  { -webkit-transform: translateX(-230px) !important;
          -ms-transform: translateX(-230px) !important;
          transform: translateX(-230px) !important;}
  100%  { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) !important;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px) !important;
        transform: translateX(0px) !important;}
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0% {  -webkit-transform: translateX(-230px) !important;
          -ms-transform: translateX(-230px) !important;
          transform: translateX(-230px) !important;}
  100% {  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px) !important;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px) !important;
        transform: translateX(0px) !important;}
}
```

this is the javascript code:

```
this.sideNav = document.querySelector('.side-nav-mobile');

this.sideNav.classList.toggle('hide');
```

And this is the HTML code

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav class="side-nav-mobile hide" mode="side" opened>

    // A lot of content here

  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Note: I used transition before but it didn't work on IOS, even after adding prefixes, so I have to use keyframes but they don't work anywhere, what is wrong with my code?

Another note: I tried to use those keyframes on other elements and it won't work too.

Comment: Please add your HTML as well. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When you tried `transition`, did you write `-webkit-transform: transition` or `-webkit-transform: -webkit-translate`? Only the latter works on older iOS.

Comment: I added HTML code

Comment: yes I did, but it didn't work though

Comment: OK, because in the code you shared, you have written it `-webkit-transform: transition` without the prefix on transition.